# Passing an input via pipes to systemctl command

Tags: linux, pipe, systemctl

I'm exploring systemd and tried my hand at monitoring a service from a remote server. When I run **`systemctl --host root@Server_2_IP status test.service`** on my Server 1 then I get:

> **root@Server_2_IP password:**

i.e. I've to enter the account password of Server_2 after which I get the status of "test.service".

When I tried to pass the password via pipe, it failed i.e. **`echo "password" | systemctl --host root@Server_2_IP status test.service`**
 is not working(I still have to enter the password). What's wrong?

Comment: As far as I know systemctl does not read the password from stdin. Sudo does the same, but has a flag (-S) to read the password from stdin, I don't know if systemctl has something similar.

Comment: Probably not, at least not according to a quick read of its man page.